# Updating the .shadowCameraNear and .shadowCameraFar property not working

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

There is a very weird problem with the `.shadowCameraNear` and `.shadowCameraFar` property of the directional light.

I'm trying to update this property dynamically (for instance in the animation loop), the value changes - but it has no effect on the `shadowCamera`. When I log the property after the update it says it has changed, but it's not working.

Comment: I answered this question for you elsewhere... Can you provide a link to a live example to demonstrate the issue you are still having?